# google map getZoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have a problem with google maps.
When place marker, to set lat, lng and zoom level to hidden fields, lat and lng works, but zoom doesn't.

I tried with marker.map.getZoom(), but still nothing.

Here is my code:

```
var map,
    map_container = document.getElementById("map"),
    mapLat = document.getElementById("mapLat"),
    mapLng = document.getElementById("mapLng"),
    markersArray = [],
    adresa;

var marker = {
    init : function() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44, 20);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(map_container, myOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
            marker.placeMarker(event.latLng);
            mapLat.value = event.latLng.lat();
            mapLng.value = event.latLng.lng();
        });

    },

    placeMarker : function(location) {
        marker.deleteMarkers();

        var map_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });

        markersArray.push(map_marker);

        console.log(map.GetZoom());

        $('#mapZoom').val(map.GetZoom());

    },

    deleteMarkers : function() {
        if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markersArray.length = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

how can i fix this ?
Thanks.

Comment: What javascript errors do you get?  GetZoom() and getZoom() are different things (javascript is case sensitive), your posted code uses GetZoom() which is not part of the Google Maps API v3.

Comment: I just saw it now, it was GetZoom, but need getZoom.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetZoom() and getZoom() are different things (javascript is case sensitive), your posted code uses GetZoom() which is not part of the Google Maps API v3.